# python - Not sure if recursive or not

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```
def func_palindrome(stri):
    if len(stri) == 0 or 1:
        return True
    if stri[0] != stri[-1]:
        return False
    return func_palindrome(stri[1:-1])
```

I'm not sure if this function, that checks if the string is a palindrome can be considered as a recursive code or not. That becuase I can simply change the **last** return value from `return func_palindrome(str[1:-1])` to True and nothing will change

Comment: yes, but if should fail for `func_palindrome('a')`

Comment: If a function calls itself, it is recursive. Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say if you change the return to True it stays the same...that does not look to be the case at all...

Comment: @alko: What do you mean? can you explain it more please?

Comment: You should never name a variable after a built-in.  Doing so overshadows them.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: @mattedgod: if I change the last return value... instead of writing the name again, just putting "True"

Comment: @user2969278 Right, that completely changes what the function does. Now you are just checking the first and last characters (once you fix the bug that karthik pointed out in an answer that is)

Comment: @mattedgod ok, so lets say I've changed the if condition but keep the value of the last return to "func...", it will be considered as a recursive code or not? It will work?

Comment: @user2969278 If the function calls itself, it is recursive. As long as you are calling `func_palindrome` from within `func_palindrome` it is recursive.

Comment: @mattedgod yes, I know that if the func calls itself it is recursive... but I don't get the connection between the if condition to that it will be recursive or not... I mean, I've change the condition in the code. so now it's not recursive?

Comment: @user2969278, let me say in other words: did you test your solution on any testcase before posting question?

Comment: @alko yes, I've tested the code before posting it here...

Answer (score 7):

Your issue is here:

```
if len(str) == 0 or 1 :
```

should be

```
if len(str) == 0 or len(str) == 1:
```

By just doing `if len(str) == 0 or 1` it is evaluating to `True` *always* as it is interpreted as `(len(str) == 0) or 1`

Also, I would rename `str` to something else, as `str` is a builtin type

Comment: you don't give student chance to find an answer himsef; and you don't answers the question asked, you answer next one; it's only my opinion though, as a others students teacher

Comment: But now I know where is my mistake... at least one of mine

Comment: you'd better learn your mistakes by correcting them yourself, p.ex. if you fail with this solution, you'll learn to test your code thoroughly. sorry for offtopic, me I too do not always act sportsmanlike

Comment: karthikr's comments on the code seem constructive and genuinely helpful rather than simply giving-away-the-answer.  This is especially true as it the issue is primarily an issue of syntax and grammar rather than fundamental misunderstanding of concepts (you could argue otherwise in this case, but I disagree).

Answer (score 1):

Any function that calls itself is technically a recursive function.

Any function that checks its arguments for a "base case", and otherwise calls itself with a "smaller" version of its arguments, is a usefully recursive function.

Of course a recursive function can still be broken, or even pointless. For example, consider this function:

```
def recursive_length(a):
    if not a:
        return 0
    return 0 + recursive_length(a[1:])
```

My stupid bug in the last line doesn't mean this is not a recursive function. I'm recursively summing up N copies of the number `0`, instead of N copies of the number `1`, so I could have done the same thing by just writing `return 0`. But that's just because the sum of N copies of `0` is always `0`, not because my function fails to be recursive.

So, what if there were a problem in the base case?

```
def recursive_length(a):
    if a is not None:
        return 0
    return 1 + recursive_length(a[1:])
```

Now, it never actually recurses… but it's still a recursive function. It's just a recursive function with a bug in the base case.

Comment: I'm a little confused. So, what you want to say is that my code is a recursive but not actually recurses?

Comment: @user2969278: Yes. What's wrong with that? If you write a correct `recursive_length`, then call `recursive_length([])`, it won't recurse. Does that mean the function isn't recursive?

Comment: So because of `stri[1:-1]` it's not a "real" recursive function?
Therefore, how can I change it so it will be a "reall" one?

Comment: @user2969278: Nothing about `str[1:-1]` makes it not a real recursive function. That definitely counts as a smaller version of your arguments. And you definitely have a base case. So it's a usefully recursive function. There is a _bug_ in your base case, as explained by karthikr, but that just means it's a _buggy_ recursive function.

Comment: @abarnet: so if I change the base case to what karthikr wrote, it will not be buggy recursive function anymore?

Comment: @user2969278: karthikr's answer fixes the bug in your base case. As to whether that's the only bug—well, I don't see anything else wrong with your code, and it certainly gives the right result in obvious cases like `''`, `'a'`, `'ab'`, `'aba'`, `'abba'`. But that's not _proof_ that it's correct; it's up to you to do enough analysis and/or testing to convince yourself (which is often as much of an art as a science).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this recursively, but you can, particularly if you don't mind a lot of extra space and poor performance for long strings.

Here are two nonrecursive ways:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def is_palindrome1(string1):
    string2_list = list(string1)
    string2_list.reverse()
    string2 = ''.join(string2_list)
    return string1 == string2

def is_palindrome2(string):
    len_string = len(string)
    for index in range(len_string // 2):
        character1 = string[index:index+1]
        character2 = string[len_string-index-1:len_string-index]
        if character1 == character2:
            # This character is good
            pass
        else:
            return False
    # all characters matched
    return True

for string in [ '393', '339', 'aibohphobia', 'aibobphobia' ]:
    assert is_palindrome1(string) == is_palindrome2(string)
    print(is_palindrome1(string))
    print(is_palindrome2(string))
```